# how to zoom out on an chrome extension's popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromebook

Some extensions' popup windows don't fit nicely into the page. If I can zoom out on the popup window, I can use it as normal, but there's no apparent way to do this.

Example screenshot: [image: img]

you can see that the popup window extends below the visible portion of the screen. There's a button on the bottom that says "record tab" which I can't manage to click.

My chrome build:

```
Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)
Platform 8350.68.0 (Official Build) stable-channel orco
Firmware Google_Orco.5216.362.7
```

All this is with my page zoom set to 100% and font-size set to medium in the `about://settings` menu.

Adjusting the page zoom to 75% in `about://settings` fixed it for about 30 seconds but the popup soon reverted back to its original zoom level.

Comment: Eh, Chrome is supposed to limit extension popup size automatically so that it fits on screen. Failure to do so is certainly a bug that should be reported on https://crbug.com if it's not there already. As a temporary fix you can rightclick the popup and in the devtools inspector add `max-height: 80vh;` CSS property to `html` element.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't fix it. the text is the same size and just cuts off further from the bottom. I guess I will submit a bug report though.

Comment: off topic as is not about programming. try superuser forum. try to click the popup, then type ctrl - (zoom out)

Comment: @ZigMandel didn't work, but i've noted your off-topic comment. Can you vote to migrate?

Comment: Huh, I guess that extension disabled overflow property. Well, use CSS transform then: `transform: scale(0.75);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted answer mentions going to the extension's options page to reset the zoom, but many extensions don't have/need an options page.

If that is the case:

1. Open the popup
2. Right-click and "Inspect"
3. A "Developer Tools" window should open, and in the title bar it should say the name and path of the popup html file, like this: `chrome-extension://[the extension ID, a long string of random letters]/popup.html`
4. Open that long address in a new tab, and it should show the normal popup content. (Instead of typing out the extension id manually, it can be copy/pasted from `chrome://extensions` with "Developer mode" on.)
5. Reset the zoom there to the default 100% (ctrl+0), as most extension developers will design and test assuming 100%.

The key point here is, **the zoom is global/consistent across all of the extension's pages, including the popup**, which is why zooming the "options" page works. Any page beginning within `chrome-extension://[the extension ID]` will have the same zoom as and affect the zoom of all the other pages.

For example, my extension's popup has a question mark icon that navigates to a separate help.html page still within the popup, and the zoom there affects the main popup.html zoom as well.

This also applies to webpages. Zoom is maintained over all pages from the same domain. If you zoom from 125% to 150% on one stackoverflow.com question, a different stackoverflow.com question in another tab will also zoom to 150%.

Comment: I'm not sure how these popups accidentally get zoomed in, but it's happened to me several times in the past... and it was really tricky to finally figure out what was actually going on. Once it's become zoomed in, even uninstalling and reinstalling the app doesn't fix it, in my experience. Chrome somehow remembers the zoom.

Comment: This solution no longer works. Would greatly appreciate some new recommendations.

CHROME VERSION: 78.0.3904.108
OS VERSION: Linux: 4.15.0-65-generic

Comment: Just tested this myself, and can confirm it doesn't work anymore. Even trying the other answer (for extensions that have options pages) doesn't work. My guess is that the Chromium team recently made a change that forces popups to be 100% zoom, regardless of the zoom on other pages in the extension.

Answer (score 2):

The zoom setting for a Chrome extension can be managed on that extension's options page:

1. Right click on the extension
2. Click on Options
3. Zoom In or Out  using ctrl +/-

Now, click on the extension and watch the magic!

Google Chrome saves your zoom levels on a per-site basis. When one adjusts the zoom level on an extension’s options page, that level also applies to that extension’s popups.

Source: [How to prevent zooming in popup window in my Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904424/how-to-prevent-zooming-in-popup-window-in-my-chrome-extension#answer-25927325)

Comment: What if your extension doesn't have an options page

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the extension, opening the popup HTML separately might not be feasible. I suggest setting the non-standard [CSS zoom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom) directly for the extension's popup:

1. Open the extension's popup and right-click.
2. Select `Inspect` to open the Chrome Developer Tools.
3. Select the `html` tag in the `Elements` tab, and add to the styles the `zoom` property with the desired value. To zoom out, use a value < 1 (e.g., 0.75).

Comment: Easy, but not sustainable. By the next use of extension, the zoom property on the HTML node is not present.